# How do you connect to a remote emacs server using Microsoft dev tunnels

Tags: windows, emacs, dev-tunnels

VSCode supports connecting directly to a remotely running vscode server over a Microsoft dev tunnel https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/dev-tunnels/get-started

I would like to replicate this technique using Emacs. Theoretically it should be possible but I have not been able to do it. When I run my `emacsclient` with the server file pointing to the dev tunnel, I get this output

```
emacsclient -f ~/.emacs.d/server/remote .
emacsclient: connected to remote socket at 255.255.255.255
emacsclient: connect: Address family not supported by protocol family
emacsclient: error accessing server file "/Users/cowboyd/.emacs.d/server/remote"
```

Is this a case of misconfiguration, or is it simply not possible?

To be clear, tramp/ssh is not an option. I am specifically wondering how to use emacsclient over a dev tunnel.